# Using multiple list in a glossary a-z index

Tags: list, web-part, index

I've been searching for a A-Z Index web part and all i found looks the same, a top bar with A-Z letters and then it searches inside a `list` content with the selected letter.

My purpose is to have it displayed like a glossary and use multiple lists. Is it possible? The lists i want to use in this A-Z Index web part could contain all stuff like documents and announcements at the same time and everything would be displayed on the same page.

Usually a glossary contains definitions to different words but i'm searching for something that would only look like a glossary but containing a lot of different stuff.

Can we do it with no code solution? With any webparts already existing on SharePoint or some free web parts?

The different list would keep changing so It would be nice if we could use multiple lists for one webpart

Example of a glossary i would like (with documents, announcments, and other) but i don't know how to do it: http://xuse.sourceforge.net/user-guide/glossary-html.jpg

I can however add a scripteditor so listing stuff from different list and then changing how it looks like is also a possibility i guess. But then how to use more than one list in a webpart and what to use to display the webpart? a list view and change its look with css/javascript?

Answer (score 1):

For a **glossary only** I am using the **term store** for this purpose because of several things:

1. Everybody can use the same term
2. The chance to write the term wrong is not that high
3. You can manage all your terms in one place
4. Add the glossary as a managed metadata column to your list or library
5. Search can be improved because of the terms

You can e.G. find the term store manager in Central Administration -> Manage Service Applications -> Managed Metadata Service

There are also some third party apps in the store. Not tested, do not know a thing about it, but maybe also something for you.

https://store.office.com/layer2-term-set-glossary-app-free-edition-WA104379627.aspx

If you want to have **documents and other** stuff in the glossary I probably would take the search results or CSWP (Enterprise Feature) with display templates...

Comment: That's a glossary only. I'm not searching this. I need a glossary to list stuff like documents and announcments. Not terms and definitions.